# How to create my own custom version of Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter?

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb2

How to create my own custom version of Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter; so I can give it my own defined JAXB2 Marshaller via the application context xml configuration file?

Thanks,

Tonté

Answer (score 0):

Just create a sub-class of the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java and then override the necessary methods.  Or you can complete create your own class by copying and pasting the source code of the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java and then update class as necessary.